# Django Tutorial 1 - ImportError: No module named apps

Tags: python, django

I am following this Tutorial:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/

In subsection *"Activating models"* i should add some code in the

> mysite/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

when i run the command

```
python manage.py makemigrations polls
```

i get the following errormessage

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 112, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named apps
```

i don't have a folder or a file called "apps" in my "polls" folder, so i am wondering about the "polls.apps.PollsConfig" syntax. i found some posts in the web telling that in django version 1.7 there where some changes.

I am using:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Python 2.7.11+
- django.VERSION (1, 8, 7, 'final', 0)

Comment: You should use the right tutorial version for your version of Django; either use the [1.8 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/), or upgrade your installation to 1.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a newer version of Django, who doesn't create the app.py configuration file in the folder because the old structure is different. You've two options:

1) Change the documentation version to 1.8

2) [RECOMMENDED] use the latest version of Django